# Unsigned right shift in Java

Tags: java, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

Simple question: why if I apply unsigned right shift in Java to byte variable (and short as well) it threats it as int:

```
byte x = -1;
System.out.println(x >> 2);
System.out.println(x >>> 1);
System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

Console output:

```
-1
2147483647
2147483647
```

Comment: It is treated as int with almost all operators, not just unsigned right shift.

Answer (score 5):

One can only use the shift operators on ints and longs in Java (just like all other numeric operators), thus the byte is automatically cast to an int before shifting it. This also happens with the arithmetical right shift, but `-1 >> 2` is -1 no matter what type `-1` is, because the binary representation `111...111` shifted right arithmetically is still `111...111`, while shifted logically it becomes `011...111`, i.e. the maximum value of the shifted type.

PS: An arithmetic shift is a signed shift, and a logical shift is an unsigned shift.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Didn't know it.